# How to verify that a Client connecting to Server is own Client

Tags: sockets, server, tcp, client

Does anyone know a good solution to this Problem?

When a Server and a Client communicate through TCP-Sockets how can I get sure that the inquiry comes from my own Client-Application and not by any other?

Comment: When you open a port to allow internet connection, there is no way to to ensure that the inquiry comes from your own Client-Application and not by any other, you need implement a command (API) like login to validate every client connection

Comment: SSL with client authentication.